# Firefox Back Button loops a window.location.hash redirect

Tags: javascript, browser-history

So basically I want to redirect /foo to /foo#bar (bar could be different things)
The code of updating the location is:

```
window.location.hash = "#bar";
```

On chrome/safari this works fine, when I browser back from /foo#bar I came back to the origin page I was coming from.

firefox keeps the /foo in the history and when I browser back it just redirected again to /foo#bar which makes browser back not working.

Any ideas how to fix it. How can I manipulate history to prevent this.

If you want to try the real example just call https://people.sap.com/stefan.scheuermann and use browser back. It will not bring you back to here on firefox.

Thanks!

Comment: Does `history.replaceState()` work for your use case?

Comment: `history.replaceState()` works in general, it changes the url in the right way but how do I do the # redirect because its not doing anything on page.

Answer (score 0):

For us this was solved by checking if there is already a hash set:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    window.location.hash = value
} else {
    // Hash didn't exist yet: replace history to prevent loop on Firefox
    window.location.replace('#' + value)
}
```